# Retrieve all elements that have data-foo Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to get all elements by `data-foo` (a specific data- attribute name) like `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsByClassName` thanks.

***Note**: I am not using a JS library.*

Comment: Do you have a particular `data-` attribute to recover? Or all attributes with a data-prefixed attribute?

Comment: A particular one e.g. data-myatt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got one approach, in compliant browsers, so long as you know in advance the name of the attribute you're looking for, say `data-myatt`:

```
var dataElems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-myatt]');
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Knh3M/).

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [Selectors Level 3 - Attribute presence and value selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#attribute-representation)

Comment: Oh, we wouldn't want to make things *too* easy, now, would we..!? =)